# Volume.slicing_() not found

Tags: xtk

Got "Error: volume.slicing_ is not a function" when trying to experiment with this method. It is in the api doc and source code at http://api.goxtk.com/symbols/src/_Users_d_Projects_X_objects_volume.js.html.

Comment: it is a private method. what do u want to achieve?

Comment: I'd like to be able to show individual slices as single images. Is the method intended for this?

Answer (score 1):

you can probably show single images by looking at

http://jsfiddle.net/haehn/qxMtk/

and

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/xtk/lessons/tree/gh-pages/13/#run

Comment: For the second example, is there a way to see the full front view for both X and Y orientations, just like the Z orientation?

Comment: yes, you can just hide 2 and 3 to show X or 1 and 3 to show Y

Comment: I actually want to see all three together. The issue is that the X and Y orientations are shown slantingly, while the Z orientation has a full frontal view. I suspect I have to play with the camera position, but nothing was set in the example given in lesson 13. -Thanks

Comment: Non issue. The different look is caused by the smaller number of slices on the Z orientation.